# error when trying to execute a macro in one workbook from another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a multitude of reports I refresh and publish each day, and I'm trying to write a macro in a separate spreadsheet that will open each of these reports, and run the 'Refresh' macro in each workbook, then close the workbook.  Here is the code I have so far:

```
Sub Reports()
'
' Reports Macro
'
Application.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\mmarsh\Documents\Daily Reports\Daily Report.xlsm")
Applicion.Run ("'Daily Report.xlsm'!Refresh")

Workbooks("'Daily Report.xlsm'").Close
'
End Sub
```

When I execute, the code breaks at the Application.Run line and I get the following error: 
Run-time error '424': Object Required.
I'm obviously missing something in the code, and I've read several different resources but have not found a solution. Any assistance would be appreciated!

I'm running Office 2010 x64 on Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Check your spelling**

```
Applicion.Run
```

vs

```
Application.Run
```

Comment: good one Gary:) also it seems that OP should remove single quotes from this line: `Workbooks("'Daily Report.xlsm'").Close` --> `Workbooks("Daily Report.xlsm").Close`

Comment: Ugh.  thank you Gary.  Sometimes it just stares you in the face!

Comment: Simoco - the additional single quote are needed when there are spaced in the file name.  If it was DailyReport I would not need them, but because its Daily (space) Report the single quotes are needed to recoginze the file name correctly.

Comment: @MikeMarshall, it's true for `Application.Run`, but not for `Workbooks(...).Close`. I've just tested it and with single quotes I get runtime-error `subscript out of range`, but without single quotes it works well